# Distributing $m\cdot n$ identical items into $n$ distinct boxes, with $m$ distinct positions in box

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, analytic-combinatorics

There are $n$ boxes and $m\cdot n$ identical items. Each box has $m$ positions where an item can be placed. The order matters here. It is a difference if an item is placed in position 1, 2, or 3 or if two items are placed in positions 1 and 2, or 1 and 3, or 2 and 3.

How many combinations exist for up to $m\cdot n$ items placed in the $n$ boxes so that the number of boxes with more than $0$ items is exactly $t$?

I can simulate (count) this, but I do not have the combinatoric math capabilities to come up with the analytical equation.

I simulated for $n=7$ boxes with $m=3$ distinct positions in the box:

There are $49$ possible combinations for $t=1$ (items are distributed in a single box). $21 (7\cdot 3)$ when placing a single item, $21$ when placing $2$ items and $7$ when placing $3$ items.

For $t=2$, there are overall $1029$ ways to distribute items: $189$ for placing $2$ items, $378$ for $3$, $315$ for $4, 126$ for $5$ and $21$ for $6$.

And so on.

Is there a way to express this problem analytically for arbitrary $m, n,$ and $t$?

Comment: Not sure the problem is clear.  For one thing, you need to specify whether the boxes are distinguishable or not.  Either way makes sense, but of course the answers are different.  And you need to say whether you are required to use all the balls or not.  I guess you aren't, right?

Comment: t=1: If I want to distribute 1 item in a box with 3 positions, I have 3 options to place it. (position 1, 2, or 3 in the box). Then there are 7 boxes so that I have 7*3 possible ways to place the single item. For two items, I also have 3 options to place it into a single box (positions 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and 2 and 3) and again 7 boxes (3*7= 21 possible options). In case of 3 items, I need to place them all in a single box for t=1. With boxes, there are 7 options. For more then 3 items, there are no options with t=1. So, I count 21+21+7=49 possible combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the boxes are distinguishable:

There are $\binom nt$ ways to choose the $t$ non-empty boxes.  Then, for each of those, there are $(2^m-1)$ ways to pick a non-empty subset of the positions.  It follows that the desired function is $$f(n,m,t)=\binom nt\times \left(2^m-1\right)^t$$

We remark that $f(7,3,1)=49$ and $f(7,3,2)=1029$ as desired.

Comment: Mr lulu, Why is exactly $(2^m-1)^t$ but not $(2^m)^t$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  There are $2^m$ subsets in total, but here we want those $t$ boxes to be non-empty.  Therefore, we must subtract off $1$ to exclude the empty set.

Comment: Mr lulu, I have another question: why is exactly $(2^m−1)^t$ but not $(2^m-1)t$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  You can choose your subsets independently for each box, that's a product not a sum.  Work it out by hand for the case $m=2, t=2$.  You should get $9$ cases, not $6$.

Comment: Thank you, respected Mr lulu.

Comment: Thank you @lulu! This has been very helpful and very quick. I checked against a few other simulation results and it matches perfectly!

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: Mr lulu, if we must choose $1$ non-empty box of $4$ boxes with $2$ positions for each box, hence, we will get $12$ ways. Can this case be considered as an attempt to place, for instance, or $1$ white ball in the $1$ box, or $1$ green ball in the $1$ box, or $1$ white ball and $1$ green ball in the $1$ box, as we have $(2^2-1)^1=3$ ways? Such method must be accepted for the remaining second, third and fourth boxes. Am I right?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  It is critical for this problem that the balls are indistinguishable.  There aren't white and green ones, they are all the same.  That's why I was able to just think about which positions were occupied, without worrying about what occupied them.

Comment: Mr lulu, if we will consider two indistinguishable white balls, therefore, or the first indistinguishable white ball will be in the first box, or the second indistinguishable white ball will be in the first box, or the first and the second indistinguishable white balls will be in the first box. Is this method accepted for the remaining second, third and fourth boxes? Am I right? Total amount of ways will be $12$.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  Not following.  If we have $4$ boxes, each with $2$ positions, and want exactly $1$ non-empty one, then we have $(n,m,t)=(4,2,1)$ so $f(n,m,t)=f(4,2,1)=\binom 41\times (2^2-1)^1=12$, so I agree with $12$ as the answer.  In words, you first choose one box out of four (so a factor of $4$) and then you choose a non-empty subset ($3$ options), and $4\times 3=12$.

Comment: Explain, please, what do you mean when you say "positions" and "non-empty set"? Are "positions" of what? Is "non-empty set" of what? How do "positions" and "non-empty set" relate with those white balls, I have mentioned?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  I am referring to the context of the problem as originally stated.  In that problem, we are to imagine that each box has $m$ labeled positions and that putting a ball into position $\#1$ is not the same as putting it into position $\#2$.  When I speak of "sets" I am speaking of the occupied positions, viewed as a subset of the set of all the positions in the box.  If the box is to be non-empty, that subset must be non-empty.

Comment: Mr lulu, if we are returning to the suggested example by me, where we have $4$ boxes, each with $2$ positions, and want exactly $1$ non-empty box, therefore, position $\#1$ can be occupied by ball in the first box, or position $\#2$ can be occupied by ball in the first box, or and position $\#1$ and position $\#2$ can be occupied by balls in the first box. And relatively of the first box we will have $3$ ways. Also there are $3$ ways for each box of the remaining boxes: second box, third box, fourth box. Total sum of ways is $12$. Am I right?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  Yes, I already said $12$ was correct.  The possible non-empty subsets of $\{1,2\}$ are $\{1\}, \{2\},\{1,2\}$, just as you say.